# Access linked table editable from shared server but not from local server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am linking a table from my company shared SQL server to an access database. The table has a primary key. It all works fine. I can add, edit and do anything to it in access. But now my company does not want me to use their shared server anymore. I moved the table to my local server and link it to my access database. The linked table is not editable anymore! It is the exact same table.

I can not figure out why. Can anybody help, please.

Comment: Have you linked it to your MS Access database using user credentials with read/write access to the table on SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, It is Read/Write. I double checked. It is not Read Only.

Comment: Do you receive any error messages when trying to edit the records?

Comment: Nothing happens if I try to type in the table. Nothing would show up. If I right click on left side of the table all the New record, Delete Record options are grayed out. If I write a query to delete rows, I would get a massage says could not delete from Specified tables.